# re matches none: Differences in Python implementation of regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm having some trouble matching a specific pattern using the python regex library (`re`). I'm trying to match lines with a number (of up to 3 digits), followed a collection of words (with no space between the first word and the number) which are terminated by exactly two spaces. Some examples, with the matching string enclosed in parentheses:

`test(58your own becoming  )Adapted from Pyramid Text utterance 81.`

`(46ancestral fires  )In Sumerian, a language recently supplanted by`

`(45lap of God  )Ginzberg, Legends of the Bible, p. 1.`

`(9Island of the Egg  )The symbolism of the cosmic egg is an integral aspect of almost every mythological tradition. In the`

I'm using the following expression:

```
(\d+).+(  )
```

The relevant python code is as follows:

```
# the search string is `tmp`
pattern = re.compile("(\d+).+(  )")
footnotes = pattern.finditer(tmp)
for footnote in footnotes:
    # do something with each match
```

When I use a testing site like regexr, all the above examples match exactly as intended. However, python matches none. Is there something simple I'm missing? I've also tried passing the expression to `re` as a raw string. I can't seem to find anything else to try in the documentation. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

## EDIT

The full string can be found [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rosslaird/stone/master/stone.md?token=AA8QrJsY8fTR7zxEcL-U-lyJh8jGKaNlks5ZkmxFwA%3D%3D).

At this point, I'm fairly certain it has something to do with how I'm handling the string. If I read from a text file, and execute the following code, the output is empty:

```
with open("stone.md", "r+") as f:
    tmp = f.read()
    pattern = re.compile(r"(\d+).+  ")
    footnotes = pattern.finditer(tmp)
    for footnote in footnotes:
        print tmp[footnote.start():footnote.end()]
```

But, If I run:

```
tmp = """test58your own becoming  Adapted from Pyramid Text utterance 81."""
pattern = re.compile(r"(\d+).+  ")
footnotes = pattern.finditer(tmp)
for footnote in footnotes:
    print tmp[footnote.start():footnote.end()]
```

I get `58your own becoming`

Comment: Are you using `.match` or `.search`? One only finds matches at the start of the string

Comment: Can you show the value of `tmp`?

Comment: You probably want a non-greedy quantifier, ".+?" instead of ".+".

Comment: @Eric I'm using finditer(), which returns a MatchObject for every non-overlapping match in the string

Comment: @Eric Also `tmp` is quite large. The provided examples give a good idea of typical examples, however

Comment: Provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show your attempt. Btw, it look strange to me that you are putting that 2 spaces in its own group.  And, what are you trying to achieve? just to check if the string match? or do you want to extract the number or some text from the string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You've fallen victim to Unicode homoglyphs.

Your regex contains ASCII-encoded space characters (the regular spaces you are used to). However, the full text that you are operating on contain non-breaking spaces, which in HTML is `&nbsp;` and in Unicode `U+00A0`. It looks exactly like a regular space to the human eye, but it isn't an ASCII space.

```python
Python 3.6.2 (default, Jul 20 2017, 03:52:27) 
[GCC 7.1.1 20170630] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> '  '.encode('ascii')
b'  '
>>> '  '.encode('ascii')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> '  '.encode('utf-8')
b'\xc2\xa0\xc2\xa0'
```

The following regex will give you what you want:

`pattern = re.compile(b'(\d+).+(\xc2\xa0)'.decode('utf-8'))`

What this is doing is constructing a bytes object then decoding it to a utf-8 string so `re` can work with it.

Or, even better, you can use `\s`, which matches any whitespace character (covers Unicode) in the regex flavor you're using:

`pattern = re.compile('(\d+).+(\s\s)')`

### Why then, did the regex in your answer appear to work?

**Because browsers render the non-breaking space as an ASCII space**, which propagates to the browser copy paste buffer as an ASCII space.

I was only able to discover this once you had disclosed the original text file you were working on. I downloaded the raw format with `wget` on the URL, which preserved the Unicode spaces in the original file, something that would not have happened had I copy pasted your large text file in the browser to a file on my local computer.

Wow. This was a really fun puzzle to solve. Thanks for the question.

Comment: I'm fairly confident I understand how finditer works, especially since I've used it successfully in the past. In either case, my for-loop contains a print statement for debugging, which is never reached. So no MatchObjects are returned.

Comment: @avery_laird JoshuaRLi is using the exact same input, with exact same piece of code you provided, and it works.  So you need to tell how his code is different from yours, so people can get a clue on your actual problem

Comment: @avery_laird Ahh! Sorry, didn't mean to be condescending. That's weird, I'm honestly at a loss then. What's the output like on your machine when you run my exact code?

Comment: @JoshuaRLi no worries, I didn't take it as condescending, it was a valid question. Especially since my output matches yours exactly, when I run the code on my machine. This exact string is a substring of the one I use in my code, so I'm still not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: @avery_laird See my answer edit. Still works. If it helps, i'm on Arch Linux running the latest hardened linux kernel on an x86_64 CPU architecture, but python 2.7 should work the same universally. Could it be that your python 2.7 installation had the re module compiled incorrectly for some weird reason? How about doing a uninstall and reinstall?

Comment: @JoshuaRLi I could try that, but so far our output agrees. So that doesn't seem to be the problem. There must be a difference in the string I'm using, what happens when you use the text [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rosslaird/stone/master/stone.md?token=AA8QrJsY8fTR7zxEcL-U-lyJh8jGKaNlks5ZkmxFwA%3D%3D)? As a side note, I ran your second piece of code through my shell and got the same output.

Comment: @avery_laird, your regex is still fine. I read in your large file into one string, and I'm not getting any output. Then I took a small chunk of a couple paragraphs of footnotes, and it ran successfully with correct output. It might be a problem with the size of the in-memory string, but it's only 541 KB...

Comment: @JoshuaRLi I am having the same problem (see my edited answer). I will see if reading the file line by line changes things.

Comment: @avery_laird I was able to get to the root of the problem once you disclosed the text file you were operating on. See my edited solution. This was really fun :)

Comment: A note: since OP is using Python 2.7, to make `\s` match all Unicode whitespace, the `re.UNICODE` flag should be passed to the `re` method. In Python 3.x, since the strings are Unicode by default, `\s` matches all Unicode whitespace by default.

Comment: @JoshuaRLi what a rabbit hole! Great answer,  thank you for your help.

Comment: @avery_laird It was my pleasure to help. Definitely learned something from this...I need to be more Unicode aware.